# ReactNative ActivityIndcator causes RSOD

Tags: react-native

I am unable to import and successfully use `ActivityIndcator` without getting the following screen.

[image]

I am not doing anything special and my code looks like the following

```
import { View, Text, ActivityIndicator } from 'react-native';

...

...

render(){
   return (
       <ActivityIndicator animating={true} />
   )
}
```

If I change this to `ActivityIndicatorIOS` it works perfectly fine.

My React Native and React Native CLI versions are the following

```
react-native-cli: 0.2.0
react-native: 0.27.2
```

Full Stack Trace Is

```
import { ActivityIndicator, StyleSheet, View } from 'react-native';
```

Comment: Could you please update your question with the full stacktrace and the complete file where you try to import the `ActivityIndicator` ? I had similar issues when I was not importing a component correctly.

Comment: Cross-platform `ActivityIndicator` appeared only in version 0.28.0 , so you should upgrade you react-native

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should update to 0.28.0 or later since cross platform `ActivityIndicator` was added in [React Native 0.28.0](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/releases/tag/v0.28.0):

> Add cross platform ActivityIndicator ([26e8426](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/commit/26e84262484767dd9abdfd78ff16fa37fcb8e334)) - @janicduplessis